# From string result in cURL call to array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, wampserver

I get a response via my localhost Wampserver from Paypal mobile SDK. I receive a string via a cURL call. This string has been verified to be in json form via the online service Json Lint website. I was able to convert the json string to an array in php code, using an online php compiler, phptester.net using php version 5.5. However, when i tried the same code on my wampserver it says that the array size equals zero. I don't know what could be wrong. Please help me evaluate my PHP code.

Here's the response from Paypal mobile sdk:

```
{"scope":"https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscriptions https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks openid https://uri.paypal.com/payments/payouts https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*","nonce":"2016-03-06T22:13:44ZNxK118Mc40QthTeJX8Y_enneSe0y62kEo6mu0ICCwMU","access_token":"A101.ONfkNw-H4-VcjWL9ZUbLlaDj1YUApO7X9fhOslMKRLyW1JpKL1hLlD5W2m9xri-y.ZRF-23gpYMDQ5vWPkOsEiv8WbJC","token_type":"Bearer","app_id":"APP-80W284485P519543T","expires_in":32399}
```

Here's the relevant code i use in my php file:

```
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header_array);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $idclient.":".$sekret);  


    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;
    $arr = (array) json_decode($result);
    $token = $arr['access_token'];

    echo "here's the token oken";
    var_dump($arr);
    var_dump($token);
```

Here's the code i use in phptester.net:

```
$e ='I copied and paste the response i get from server here. noticed the
single quotes here. Maybe this is the problem';
$a = (array)json_decode($e);
$b = $a['access_token'];
var_dump($b);
```

this code accurately prints out the value of the array at "access_token', which is the access_token i need to verify payments made to PayPal.

I need to replicate this good code on my Wamp server php file. But it is not doing what is supposed to. It says the size of my array is zero, and that the variable $token is null. Please help me in evaluating my code.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this, don't try to cast `json_decode` to array. you can use second option in `json_decode` to convert it to associative arrays.
[PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$e ='{"scope":"https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscriptions https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks openid https://uri.paypal.com/payments/payouts https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*","nonce":"2016-03-06T22:13:44ZNxK118Mc40QthTeJX8Y_enneSe0y62kEo6mu0ICCwMU","access_token":"A101.ONfkNw-H4-VcjWL9ZUbLlaDj1YUApO7X9fhOslMKRLyW1JpKL1hLlD5W2m9xri-y.ZRF-23gpYMDQ5vWPkOsEiv8WbJC","token_type":"Bearer","app_id":"APP-80W284485P519543T","expires_in":32399}';

$a = json_decode($e,true);

$b = $a['access_token'];

var_dump($b);
```

here

Comment: Yes. But how do I use this in my PHP file. I get the cURL string response like this: $result = curl_execute($ch); how do I write the single quotes around $result. Look at my PHP file implementation above. @DeveloperH

Comment: change your code to this
`$arr =  json_decode($result, true);

    $token = $arr['access_token'];`

Comment: Okay. I think I found what the problem is. The result string returned from Paypal includes other characters that nullify the string as Json format. I need to find a way to get rid of those characters in the string to turn it into Json format.

Comment: I thought you provide paypal  json string as its. Anyway you can rid that characters by regex. also try to use `json_last_error_msg()`

Comment: No it was easier than this. It works now. I just set curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true) to false. This got rid of the header in the return string from PayPal. I was then able to JSON decode the string to an array and access the access_token index.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer to my problem. I just had to get rid of the header which was returned in the returned string from PayPal. I did this by setting the following cURL option to false: curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true)

Then, I was able to use json_decode() on the returned string to convert it to an array, which allowed me to access the access_token index field in the array.

Now, I just need to store this string on my online database for purchase verification via PayPal mobile SDK.